# Rotating Barcode Aspx/html

Tags: html, css, asp.net

In an .aspx file I have this html in my Head tag to hopefully rotate things 90 degrees

```
<style>
  .rotate{
    writing-mode:tb-rl;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:block;
    font-size:8pt;
  }
</style>
```

In my body I have this:

```
          <td class="rotate"><span id="Barcode" runat="server" />&nbsp;</td>

          <td class="rotate"><span id="123" content="123" runat="server" />&nbsp;</td>

                            <td class="rotate"><span id="abc" content="abc" runat="server" />&nbsp;</td>

          <td class="rotate"><span id="456" content="456" runat="server" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="xyz" content="xyz" runat="server" /></td>

          <td class="rotate"><span id="def" content="def" runat="server" />&nbsp;</td>

           <td class="rotate"><span id="789" content="789" runat="server" />&nbsp;</td>

                            <td class="rotate" style="line-height:7mm">&nbsp;</td>

          </tr>
```

Everything shows rotated 90 degrees as needed other than the barcode, that shows horizontally still.  How can I get this to rotate 90 degrees as well?

Tried different versions of css to no avail

Answer (score 0):

Set the object position to absolute

```
<style>
  .rotate{
    writing-mode:tb-rl;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:block;
    font-size:8pt;
  }

  #Barcode {position: absolute;}
</style>
```

Comment: Sorry that didn't work. The positioning is fine other than I need the barcode rotated 90 degrees so it's vertical. At the moment it's horizontal